# Accessing HTTP Request context after handler

Tags: http, go, middleware

In my logging middleware (first in chain) I need to access some context that is written in some auth middleware futher down the chain and only after the handler itself is executed.

*Side note: The logging middleware needs to be called first since I need to log the duration of the request including the time spend in middleware. Also the auth middleware is able to abort a request when permissions are not sufficient. in that case I need to log the failed request as well.*

My problem with that is that reading the context from the `http.Request` pointer does not return the auth data I would expect it to have. See the example bellow:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

const (
    contextKeyUsername = "username"
)

func authMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := r.Context()
        ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, contextKeyUsername, "user123")
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}

func logMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer func(start time.Time) {
            ctx := r.Context()
            username := ctx.Value(contextKeyUsername)
            if username != nil {
                fmt.Printf("user %s has accessed %s, took %d\n", username,
                    r.URL.Path, time.Since(start).Milliseconds())
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("annonyous has accessed %s, took %d\n",
                    r.URL.Path, time.Since(start).Milliseconds())
            }
        }(time.Now())
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func welcome(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    username := ctx.Value(contextKeyUsername)
    if username != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, fmt.Sprintf("hello %s", username.(string)))
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello")
    }
}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/welcome", welcome)
    chain := logMiddleware(authMiddleware(mux))
    http.ListenAndServe(":5050", chain)
}
```

While a get request to `127.0.0.1:5050/welcome` does return the expected string `hello user123`, the output of the log is:

```
annonyous has accessed /welcome, took 0
```

Since the request is passed along as pointer I would have expected that at the time the defer is executed, the context would contain the expected `username` value.

What am I missing here?

Comment: [`WithContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.19.1#Request.WithContext) returns a shallow copy of `r`, i.e. the request created by the `authMiddleware` is not the same request as the one that `logMiddleware` is reading the context from.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks! That explains that... Can you imagine an elegant way to promote an information from `authMiddleware` to the defer of `logMiddleware`?

Comment: You could have the root middleware (in this case that's logMiddleware) create the context with value and the shallow request copy, but instead of a plain string store an non-nil pointer in the context, then have the authMiddleware use pointer indirection to assign the value to which the pointer points, then the logMiddleware, after next exits, can dereference that pointer to access that value. To avoid the ugly dereferencing, instead of a pointer to a string, you can use a pointer to a struct with a string field. Perhaps not elegant, but it will work.

Comment: Example based on the above comment: https://go.dev/play/p/N7vmjQ7iLM1

Comment: @mkopriva you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @mkopriva That works pretty well, and yes, you should definitely provide this as a proper answer so you get the credits ;-)

Comment: I came up with a different approach. It is a bit more readable but as far as I know considered _pretty bad_. However I am not exactly sure why, so I've posted another related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73956273/why-should-an-incoming-http-request-not-be-modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`WithContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.19.1#Request.WithContext) returns a shallow copy of the request, i.e. the request created by the `authMiddleware` is not the same request as the one from which `logMiddleware` is reading the context.

You could have the root middleware (in this case that would be the `logMiddleware`) create the context-with-value and the shallow request copy, but instead of a plain string store an **non-nil pointer** in the context, then have the `authMiddleware` use pointer indirection to assign the value to which the pointer points, then the `logMiddleware`, after `next` exits, can dereference that pointer to access that value.

And to avoid the unpleasant dereferencing, instead of a pointer to a string, you can use a pointer to a struct with a string field.

```golang
type ctxKey uint8

const userKey ctxKey = 0

type user struct{ name string }

func logMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        u := new(user)
        r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), userKey, u))

        defer func(start time.Time) {
            if u.name != "" {
                fmt.Printf("user %s has accessed %s, took %s\n", u.name, r.URL.Path, time.Since(start))
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("annonyous has accessed %s, took %s\n", r.URL.Path, time.Since(start))
            }
        }(time.Now())

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

```golang
func authMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if u, ok := r.Context().Value(userKey).(*user); ok {
            u.name = "user123"
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

```golang
func welcome(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if u, ok := r.Context().Value(userKey).(*user); ok && u.name != "" {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello %s", u.name)
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello")
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/N7vmjQ7iLM1